# Detect formattings in Excel

Tags: ruby, excel, formatting

Is there a way to detect a formatting in excel, like the color name or code?:
[image]

I am currently using Roo to parse the excel and wonder if it's possible with Roo or other gems you can recommend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just examine the `Color` property of the `Range` object:

```
Sub dural()
   MsgBox ActiveCell.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

[image]